# grep for two patterns independently (in different lines)

Tags: bash, grep

I have some directories with the following structure:

```
DAY1/ # Files under this directory should have DAY1 in the name.
|-- Date
|   |-- dir1 # Something wrong here, there are files with DAY2 and files with DAY1.
|   |-- dir2
|   |-- dir3
|   |-- dir4
DAY2/ # Files under this directory should all have DAY2 in the name.
|-- Date
|   |-- dir1
|   |-- dir2 # Something wrong here, there are files with DAY2, and files with DAY1.
|   |-- dir3
|   |-- dir4
```

In each `dir` there are hundreds of thousands of files with names containing `DAY`, for example `0.0000.DAY1.01927492`. Files with `DAY1` on the name should only appear under parent directory `DAY1`.

Something went wrong when copying files around, so that I now have mixed files with `DAY1` and `DAY2` in some of the `dir` directories.

I wrote a script to find folders that contain mixed files, so I can then look at them more closely. My script is the following:

```
for directory in */; do
    if ls $directory | grep -q DAY2 ; then
        if ls $directory | grep -q DAY1; then 
              echo "mixed files in $directory";
        fi ; 
    fi; 
done
```

The problem here is that I'm going through all files twice, which doesn't make sense considering that I'd only have to look through the files once.

What would be a more efficient way achieve what I want?

Comment: What if you just use `find` to get files and remove them if they do not belong where they should? `find DAY2/ -name "*dir2" -delete`

Comment: I can't delete them. I'll have to put them in the right place later. The thing is I want to understand why and when that happened, and how many files are mixed.

Comment: Then you can try with `man find` to print whatever you prefer. You can select file name, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, then you need to find the files under `DAY1` directory recursively that have `DAY2` in their names, similarly for `DAY2` directory the files what have `DAY1` in their names.

If so, for `DAY1` directory:

```
find DAY1/ -type f -name '*DAY2*'
```

this will get you the files under `DAY1` directory that have `DAY2` in their names. Similarly for `DAY2` directory:

```
find DAY2/ -type f -name '*DAY1*'
```

Both are recursive operations.

---

To get the directory names only:

```
find DAY1/ -type f -name '*DAY2*' -exec dirname {} +
```

Note that the `$PWD` will be shown as `.`.

To get uniqueness, pass the output to `sort -u`:

```
find DAY1/ -type f -name '*DAY2*' -exec dirname {} + | sort -u
```

Comment: There are too many files. Is there a way to have find return only the folder names, and only once?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the difference between going through them once and going through them twice is just a factor-of-two difference, changing to an approach that goes through them only once might actually *not* be a win, since the new approach might easily take twice as long per file.

So you'll definitely want to experiment; it's not necessarily something that you can confidently reason about.

However, I will say that in addition to going through the files twice, the `ls` version also *sorts* the files, which probably has a more-than-linear cost (unless it's doing some kind of bucket-sort). Eliminating that, by writing `ls --sort=none` instead of just `ls`, will actually improve your algorithmic complexity, and is almost certain to give a tangible improvement.

---

But FWIW, here's a version that only goes through the files once, that you can try:

```
for directory in */; do
  find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 \( -name '*DAY1*' -or -name '*DAY2*' \) -print0 \
  | { saw_day1=
      saw_day2=
      while IFS= read -d '' subdirectory ; do
        if [[ "$subdirectory" == *DAY1* ]] ; then
          saw_day1=1
        fi
        if [[ "$subdirectory" == *DAY2* ]] ; then
          saw_day2=1
        fi
        if [[ "$saw_day1" ]] && [[ "$saw_day2" ]] ; then
          echo "mixed files in $directory"
          break
        fi
      done
    }
done
```

Comment: This is currently returning `find: paths must precede expression: 1`

Comment: @DanielG: Whoops, I'm sorry; I wrote `-depth 1` instead of `-maxdepth 1`. Will fix.